# v.net.allpairs - Missing parameter value: WHERE condition SQL statement without where keyword

Tags: qgis, network, grass-7.4

v.net.allpairs is not running in QGIS 2.18.27 (but runs in QGIS 2.14).
QGIS 2.18.27 has responded: *Missing parameter value: WHERE condition SQL statement without where keyword*.
How to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

`where` parameter is optional, at less in GRASS GIS [`v.net.allpairs`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/v.net.allpairs.html) function.

I don't know why QGIS is asking for it as required.

Expand the *Advanced parameters* section in the algorithm GUI and use `*` (an asterisk) in the *WHERE conditions of SQL statement without 'where' keyword* box if you want to select all nodes of node layer.

If you want to select some nodes you can write the SQL sentence (without the WHERE keyword) there.